# Identify the step number were protractor test failed

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automation, jasmine, protractor

I am developing tightly coupled Protractor + Jasmine automation system  with our test cases management system.

Steps in test procedure also documented in test script also, when ever protractor test cases fails, I want to identify in which step this is failed and reported in XML

example Test expected like this

@step1 
login_page.enterUserName('user1');

@step2 
login_page.enterPassword('password');

@step3
home_page = login_page.selectLogin();

If this test failed @ step2, this should be reported in XML ,any thought ?

Comment: can you not use jasmine reporters? https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jasmine-reporters](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters).

```
framework: "jasmine2",
onPrepare: function() {
  var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    filePrefix: 'xmloutput',
    savePath: 'testresults'
  }));
}
```